# comparing histograms with matlab through pdist2

Tags: matlab, histogram, cell-array

I'm trying to compare the histogram of an image (hsv)  with a cell array that contains the histograms of other images in order to find out the closest matches.
This is what I have so far:

Image to compare with database:

```
    im=imread(name);
    resizedImage = imresize(im,[75 75]);
    image = rgb2hsv(resizedImage);
    H = image(:,:,1);
    [hist, COLORBINS]= imhist(H);
    hist_Testing=hist';
```

Images to compare:

```
    im=imread(fileName);
    resizedImage = imresize(im,[75 75]);
    image = rgb2hsv(resizedImage);

    H = image(:,:,1);

    DATA {i,1}= histogram(H);
```

the histogram class is represented as this:

```
function [hist] = histogram(H)
[hist, COLORBINS]= imhist(H);
hist=hist';
end
```

Through the pdist2 method this is my usage:

```
compHist= pdist2(hist_Testing,  hist, 'euclidean');
```

The error it gives me is "not enough arguments input".
Can someone please help me?

Comment: If `hist_Testing` and `hist` are both matrices (not cells) with the same number of columns, you shouldn't get this error. As a side note, you may explore other distances such as `histogram intersection` to compare two histograms.

Comment: thank you for your help, @ParagS.Chandakkar. How can I access the cells instead?

Comment: @jPratas If you're asking how to access cells, it's `C{1}` so use curly brackets instead of the standard `(1)`

Comment: There is no need to use `cells`. You are saving the output of `histogram` function in `DATA{i,1}`. You should save it in `DATA(i,:)` (notice the difference). Then if you give `DATA` and `hist_testing` as arguments to `pdist2`, you shouldn't get an error.